# Dagger 2 customizing provided retrofit

Tags: android, dependency-injection, kotlin, retrofit2, dagger-2

I'm looking for a better way to manage my retrofit DI. My app could call for several variations of retrofit: non-retryable, longer timeouts, cached or non-cached etc.

I've worked out I can use named params and specify a different kind of okhttp/retrofit to be provided when I use it, but it means I have to make a different provided function for every possible combination, and maintain the strings for the named params. I can see my NetworkModule class becoming very large then.

**NetworkModule.kt**

```
@Module
class NetworkModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideHttpLoggingInterceptor(): HttpLoggingInterceptor {
        val loggingInterceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor { message -> Timber.d(message) }
        loggingInterceptor.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY
        return loggingInterceptor
    }

    @Provides
    @Named("standard")
    @Singleton
    fun provideOkHttpClient(httpLoggingInterceptor: HttpLoggingInterceptor): OkHttpClient {
        val httpClientBuilder = OkHttpClient.Builder()
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) httpClientBuilder.addInterceptor(httpLoggingInterceptor)
        return httpClientBuilder.build()
    }

    @Provides
    @Named("standard")
    @Singleton
    fun provideRetrofit(@Named("baseUrl") baseUrl: String, @Named("standard") okHttpClient: OkHttpClient): Retrofit {
        return Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                .build()
    }
}
```

**LoginApiModule.kt**

```
@Module(includes = arrayOf(NetworkModule::class))
class LoginApiModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    internal fun provideLoginApi( @Named("standard") retrofit: Retrofit): LoginService {
        return retrofit.create(LoginService::class.java)
    }
}
```

In this example I would need a `provide<some specialization>OkHttpClient()` function for every specialization:

- one for a longer timeout
- one for non-retryability
- one for both
- one for caching
- one for caching with a longer timeout
- one for cachine with non-retryability etc. etc.

Comment: so you want to achieve this with only a single provide function?

Comment: Yeah I think so! Maybe it's not possible, and I should just use different module classes?

Comment: Still thinking about it. But why different module classes. The functions would be in a single (network) module, right?

Comment: it is very ugly, but you could have a set of `@Named` provides methods

Comment: @Yashasvi Well instead of one module having 10 okhttp / retrofit `@Provides`, I could have 10 network modules and each api module can include the one it needs. I _think_ that's neater, but it's hard to tell :D

Comment: haha, 10 network modules doesn't seem neat to me :) tomorrow if you want to look at all these methods at once, you won't be able to find them at one place.

Comment: You could use a completely different approach and create a custom `CallAdapter` where you call OkHttp methods directly and can use annotations on a per-call basis to communicate your needs to the adapter, possibly along with interceptors for even more options

Comment: You can also have a factory that creates your http clients based on a given criteria and provide the factory in the network module. You can have a look at the multibinding capabilities of dagger too - Seems like a good use case for this too.

Answer (score 0):

You can play with multiple instances of `OkHttpClient` (that share stuff, see: https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Recipes#per-call-configuration) and network interceptors with custom headers. People used to do this for caching in the past (see: https://krtkush.github.io/2016/06/02/caching-using-okhttp-part-2.html). Also, instead of using `@Named`, try [@Qualifiers](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/inject/Qualifier.html)!